# Clear MessageService ClickEventEmitter message history

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have a component in a shared header that emits a click event with a message whenever it's clicked. I have multiple pages with components that each subscribe to this MessageService and act on click events.

The problem is that when I switch to a new page, **all** previous messages are broadcast as well as the new one.

Is there a way to clear the old messages before sending one?

**Header Button Code:**

```
<div id="applyDate">
    <button (click)="applyClick()" id="applyBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Apply</button>
</div>

applyClick(){
    this.messageService.clickEventEmitter.emit("Start^"+this.start+"|End^"+this.end);
}
```

**Component Subscription:**

```
this.subscription = this.messageService.clickEventEmitter.subscribe(message => {
    let segs = message.split("|");
    this.start = segs[0].split("^")[1];
    this.end = segs[1].split("^")[1];

    console.log(this.start);
    console.log(this.end);
});
```

When I jump to a "new page" (single page app). All of the messages sent on the previous page are sent and logged.

**Example:**

> 1. Click Header
> 2. Logs start and end (2 logs - expected)
> 3. Click to new tab
> 4. Click Header
> 5. Logs start, end, start, end (4 logs - not expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issues is that I was not destroying the subscription when the component was destroyed:

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

The bigger issue is that since I'm broadcasting similar messages to all components subscribed, they were all picking the message up and acting on it. I decided to **reset** each subscription after I *received* a message and this solved the problem.

```
subscribe = () => {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.clickEventEmitter.subscribe(message => {
        let segs = message.split("|");
        this.start = segs[0].split("^")[1];
        this.end = segs[1].split("^")[1];

        console.log(this.start);
        console.log(this.end);
        this.resetSubscription();
    });  
}

resetSubscription = () => {        
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.subscribe();
}
```